# Configure ForwardHeadersMiddleware from appsettings?

Tags: asp.net-core, appsettings

I'm trying to configure ASP.NET Core 5's [`ForwardedHeadersMiddleware`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0#forwarded-headers-middleware-options) from `appsettings.config`. I'm having trouble to set `KnownProxies` (`IList<IPAddress> KnownProxies { get; }`) and it keeps reverting back to the default value. I assume it has to do with the options machinery not knowing how to convert the `string` to an `IPAddress`, *or* `KnownProxies` only having a `getter`.

```json
{
    "ForwardedHeaders": {
        "ForwardedHeaders": "All"
        "KnownProxies": ["10.0.0.1"]
    }
}
```

```cs
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("ForwardedHeaders"));
```

- How can I achieve what I want, without doing the parsing manually?
- Can I specify the mapping somewhere generic?
- Why doesn't this throw an exception that some of my configuration could not be parsed / is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

I may propose my recipe for this:

1. Define your own options class like the following:

```cs
public class ForwardedForKnownNetworks
{
    public class Network
    {
        public string Prefix { get; set; }
        public int PrefixLength { get; set; }
    }

    public List<Network> Networks { get; set; } = new List<Network>();
    public List<string> Proxies { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

2. To make your code shorter and more agile you may need kind of helper method to resolve hostnames and/or convert parse IP addressed strings:

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IPAddress[] ResolveIP(this string? host)
    {
        return (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(host)) 
            ? Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)
            : new IPAddress[0];
    }
}
```

3. When configuring your services, you can add something similar to the following:

```cs
var forwardedForKnownNetworks = builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(ForwardedForKnownNetworks)).Get<ForwardedForKnownNetworks>();

_ = builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options => {
    options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
    forwardedForKnownNetworks?.Networks?.ForEach((network) => options.KnownNetworks.Add(new IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse(network.Prefix), network.PrefixLength)));
    forwardedForKnownNetworks?.Proxies?.ForEach((proxy) => proxy.ResolveIP().ToList().ForEach((ip) => options.KnownProxies.Add(ip)));
});
```

4. And finally your `appsettings.json` may appear like the following:

```json
{
  "ForwardedForKnownNetworks": {
    "Networks": [
      {
        "Prefix": "172.16.0.0",
        "PrefixLength": 12
      },
      {
        "Prefix": "192.168.0.0",
        "PrefixLength": 16
      },
      {
        "Prefix": "10.0.0.0",
        "PrefixLength": 8
      }
    ],
    "Proxies": ["123.234.32.21", "my.proxy.local"] // Here you can mention IPs and/or hostnames as the ResolveIP() helper will take care of that and resolve any hostname to its IP(s)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have to parse manually, but it is not too hard to set up some general code:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("ForwardedHeadersOptions").Bind(options);
    foreach (var knownProxy in builder.Configuration.GetSection("ForwardedHeadersOptions:KnownProxies").GetChildren())
    {
        options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse(knownProxy.Value!));
    }
    foreach (var knownNetwork in builder.Configuration.GetSection("ForwardedHeadersOptions:KnownNetworks")
                 .GetChildren())
    {
        options.KnownNetworks.Add(new IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse(knownNetwork.GetValue<string>("Prefix")!),
            knownNetwork.GetValue<int>("PrefixLength")!));
    }
});
```

Values that don't match simple config values will be skipped, hence why the IList KnownProxies is simply ignored. Even with recursive binding there is no properties on IPAddress to map strings or other simple values to.

However, with the above code if you pass in invalid values then the config is built at startup time and the Parse will fail with an error.

The corresponding settings in `appsettings.x.json`, e.g.:

```json
{
  "ForwardedHeadersOptions": {
    "ForwardedHeaders": "XForwardedFor,XForwardedProto",
    "KnownNetworks": [
      {
        "Prefix": "fd00::",
        "PrefixLength": 8
      },
      {
        "Prefix": "10.0.0.0",
        "PrefixLength": 8
      }
    ]
  }
}
```